# Передача обработчику нескольких параметров input

Tags: php, sql

Имеется таблица с n количеством строк(в данном примере, 12)
[image: Форма с полями]
Все строки выведены с БД в цикле. Каждая из ячеек содержит в себе input, где в атрибут value подставляется соответствующая запись из БД. Прилагаю код:

```
$bd = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dgu");

                echo "<table border='0' width='500'><tr>
                <td><b>№</b></td>
                <td><b>Направление</b></td>
                <td><b>Дисциплина</b></td>
                <td><b>Курс/Семестр</b></td>
                <td><b>Группа</b></td>
                <td><b>Вид занятия</b></td>
                <td><b>Нагрузка(часы)</b></td>
                </tr>";
        while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($bd)) 
           {
        printf ("
                <tr>
                <td><input type='text' value='$myrow[id]' size='4'></td>
                <td><input type='text' value='$myrow[profile]' size='40'></td>
                <td><input type='text' value='$myrow[discipline]' size='20'></td>
                <td><input type='text' value='$myrow[course_semestr]' size='4'></td>
                <td><input type='text' value='$myrow[group]' size='10'></td>
                <td><input type='text' value='$myrow[type]' size='15'></td>
                <td><input type='text' value='$myrow[count_hours]' size='4'></td>
                </tr>
                ");
        }
            echo "</table>";
    echo "<form method=POST action='update.php'>
       <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='Обновить'>
       </form>";
```

Как сделать так, чтобы весь этот цикл можно было отправить обработчику?. Что нужно прописать в обработчике, чтобы он принял весь этот цикл и занес обновление в базу. Что то типа эксель, где мы можем изменять произвольные ячейки, а потом сохранять сразу всю таблицу.

Comment: Начните с того, что выводите тэг form перед input, а не после.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо к каждому `<input>` присвоить соответствующее имя в виде массива, например для первых двух это будет `<input name='id[]' ...>` и `<input name='profile[]' ...>`.

В обработчике можно написать так:

```
$id_array = $profile_array = array();

if (isset($_POST['id']))
    foreach ($_POST['id'] as $value)
        $id_array[] = intval($value);

if (isset($_POST['profile']))
    foreach ($_POST['profile'] as $value)
        $profile_array[] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
```

А дальше делать с массивами `$id_array` и `$profile_array` всё что надо, например считывать поочередно по элементу из двух массивов одновременно и сохранять данные в БД.

Функции `mysql_*()` лучше не использовать, [здесь](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php) написано почему.

Comment: А скажите пожалуйста что нужно написать в обработчике что бы принять эти значения. Если я отправляю одну запись(к примеру с id = 1), то на стороне обработчика я пишу что то типа, обнови запись где параметр id равен id. И эти данные успешно "летят" в базу. Но это в случае с одной формой. А у меня по сути их 12...

Comment: А вы попробуйте в обработчике выдать всего одну строку var_dump($_REQUEST) и увидите. В данном случае будет массив из множества id и прочих параметров. Если вы хотите менять только изменившиеся знаения, то рекомендую добавить массив, например isChanged[], который по-умолчанию забит false, и меняется на true с помощью js при изменении строки.

Comment: Видимо я что то сделал не правильно... Не срабатывает. 
<?php
$bde = mysql_query("UPDATE list discipline='$id_array', profile='$profile_array'");
 if ($bde == TRUE) {
   echo "Изменения внесены";
 }
 else { echo "Изменения не внесены";}
?>

Comment: Запрос должен быть в виде `UPDATE ... WHERE id=...`, где `id` как правило автоинкрементальное уникальное число и является первичным ключем записи в БД. Скорей всего у Вас это поле в таблице БД называется `id`. Чтобы было понятнее желательно также привести код дампа структуры этой таблицы.

Comment: Да, действительно, все точно так же как Вы предположили. Дамп привести в комментарии к сожалению не получается.

Answer (score 0):

1. убрать инпут для id
2. всем остальным полям дать имена вида `<input name='data[$id][profile]' ...>`
3. В обработчике `foreach ($_POST['data'] as $id => $row) ...`
4. Перестать пользоваться функциями mysql_*

например

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET profile=:profile, discipline=:discipline, ... 
        WHERE id = :id";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $id => $row)
{
    $row['id'] = $id;
    $stmt->execute($row);
}
```